# Arduino Mbed bootloader on nrf52840

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy, bootloader, mbed, nrf52832

I use a PCB that I designed on which is mounted the E73-2G4M08S1C from Ebyte (nrf52840). I flashed the Arduino Mbed bootloader with SWD and a J-Link (J-Flash) probe with no problem.

My computer then recognizes my card as an Arduino 33 BLE: it works. I can upload software like Blinky with Arduino and my custom USB port with no problem. Directly after, the COM port disappears and I have to use the hardware reset 100 times before my computer recognizes the card again. Looks like the embedded code isn't running either. Nothing happens.

I tried to generate a binary with Arduino IDE (with the bootloader) and upload it in SWD with J-Flash. Similarly, the upload goes well but the code doesn't seem to physically run. I use starting address 0x00.

Does anyone know where the problem could come from? Thank you.

Comment: a double reset activates the bootloader. the port is handled by a code linked to your sketch or by the bootloader. the port number is different for bootloader and sketch. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89039/arduino-nano-ble-33-default-example-sketch-usbhidkeyboard-makes-the-arduino-u/89040#89040

Comment: Ok fine it explains why I have to use the hardware reset to get the COM again. I tested it and it works. I don't know why my code isn't running on the chip.

Comment: As I don't see any other COM port than the bootloader one, I think the sketch is not fully uploaded as the IDE said.